# Cardinality of the set of functions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $\Sigma = \{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$ - the finite alphabet. We consider the set of functions: $f\colon\Sigma^* \rightarrow \Sigma^* $. How to prove that the cardinality of this set is continuum?

Comment: Let $\kappa = \operatorname{card} \Sigma^\ast$. Then find out what $\kappa$ is and compute $\kappa^\kappa$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thank you, it helped